# How to delete a row from dataframe as python code?

Tags: python, function, dataframe, csv, delete-row

I'm having the function `delete_employee(self, new_employee)` which gets a csv file path and an employee credentials which I want to remove, and suppose to delete him from the file.
My function doesn't delete it and also shows this error:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison return op(a, b).
```

Can you please help me understand why it goes wrong?

```
class Employee(object):

def __init__(self, employee_id, full_name, phone, age):
    self.employee_id = employee_id
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.phone = phone
    self.age = age

class EmployeesList(object):

def __init__(self, list_of_employees):
    self.list_of_employees = list_of_employees

def open_and_read_file(self, list_of_employees):
    employees_csv_data = pd.read_csv(list_of_employees)
    return employees_csv_data

def delete_employee(self, new_employee):
    employees_csv_data = self.open_and_read_file(self.list_of_employees)
    for row in employees_csv_data.values:
        if new_employee.employee_id == str(row[0]):
            employees_csv_data = employees_csv_data[employees_csv_data.employee_id != new_employee.employee_id]
    print(employees_csv_data)
```

Comment: please give  some lines of the dataframe (a dummy version will do) to be able to understand and test your code

Comment: Hi! sure, my dataframe is:
employee_id, name, phone, age
202666202,John Smith,0501234567,25
303555303,Rachel Green,0520987654,30
404666404,Monica Geller,0544444500,28
404555403,Chandler Bing,0520987653,31
404666403,Ross Geller,0544444501,31

Comment: please edit your topic with the dataframe as python code :)